# Implementing a custom if proc in Tcl

Tags: if-statement, tcl

I am trying to implement a custom if proc in tcl, let's call it if+. For starters, I want if+ to do exactly what if is doing.

What I have so far:

```
proc if+ {expr1 body1 args} {
    if {[uplevel 1 [list expr $expr1]]} {
        uplevel 1 $body1
        return
    }
    for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $args]} {incr i 3} {
        if {[lindex $args $i] eq "else"} {
            uplevel 1 [lindex $args [expr $i+1]]
            return
        } elseif {[lindex $args $i] eq "elseif"} {
            if {[uplevel 1 [list expr [lindex $args [expr $i+1]]]]} {
                uplevel 1 [lindex $args [expr $i+2]]
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works quite well already, with one exception: When you put a return statement inside the body of one if+ block, it only returns from the if+, not from the proc that is around it. This can be seen in this simple example:

```
proc p {} {
    if+ true {
        puts A
        return
    }
    puts B
}
```

The output of this proc is 'A' and 'B', while with if instead of if+, it's just 'A'. How can I modify my if+ to resemble if exactly?

---

Follow up: The answer by Shawn is good! It works for return perfectly. Now I noticed that also continue and break do not behave as expected (which makes sense). I tried to do the same for them as for return, but it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
proc if+ {expr1 body1 args} {
    try {
        if {[uplevel 1 expr $expr1]} {
            # Mark our returns, continues, and breaks
            return -options {from-if+ 1} [uplevel 1 $body1]
        } else {
            for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $args]} {incr i 3} {
                if {[lindex $args $i] eq "else"} {
                    # Mark returns from the else branch
                    return -options {from-if+ 1} [uplevel 1 [lindex $args $i+1]]
                } elseif {[lindex $args $i] eq "elseif"} {
                    if {[uplevel 1 [list expr [lindex $args $i+1]]]} {
                        # Mark returns from the elseif branch
                        return -options {from-if+ 1} [uplevel 1 [lindex $args $i+2]]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } on continue {val options} {
        if {[dict exists $options from-if+]} {
            return $val
        } else {
            dict incr options -level
            return -options $options $val
        }
    } on break {val options} {
        if {[dict exists $options from-if+]} {
            return $val
        } else {
            dict incr options -level
            return -options $options $val
        }
    } on return {val options} {
        if {[dict exists $options from-if+]} {
            return $val
        } else {
            dict incr options -level
            return -options $options $val
        }
    }
}
```

Is it maybe not possible to stack the "try ... on" statements like this? Unfortunately the tcl documentation is a bit unclear to me.

---

Update 2:

I think the problem isn't the handling of break and continue per se, they seem to work if they are called within the if block, but not inside an elseif or else block. Maybe this is related to the for loop that is inside the if+, which is not accessed for the if part, but only for the elseif and else part?

Comment: The full syntax of `if` is a pain to emulate; it has many optional bits. What new functionality were you looking to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`try`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/try.htm) to capture the [`return`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/return.htm) and add 1 to its [level](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/return.htm#M16) so it returns from the correct function in the call stack:

```
proc if+ {expr1 body1 args} {
    try {
        if {[uplevel 1 expr $expr1]} {
            # Mark our returns so they can be told apart from one in the
            # uplevel'ed expressions
            return -options {from-if+ 1} [uplevel 1 $body1]
        } else {
            for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $args]} {incr i 3} {
                if {[lindex $args $i] eq "else"} {
                    return -options {from-if+ 1} [uplevel 1 [lindex $args $i+1]]
                } elseif {[lindex $args $i] eq "elseif"} {
                    if {[uplevel 1 [list expr [lindex $args $i+1]]]} {
                        return -options {from-if+ 1} [uplevel 1 [lindex $args $i+2]]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } on return {val options} {
        if {[dict exists $options from-if+]} {
            # Act like normal if and return the value of the body script
            return $val
        } else {
            # return called in an evaluated expression
            dict incr options -level
            return -options $options $val
        }
    }
}
```

---

This version also adds the behavior of `if` that *The return value from the command is the result of the body script that was executed, or an empty string if none of the expressions was non-zero and there was no bodyN.*

Also note the removal of the `expr` calls in the `lindex` arguments; they're not needed in this case because `lindex` can do the math itself, but if you do use `expr` for such things, [brace your `expr`-essions](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Brace+your+expr%2Dessions).

Comment: Next step: Add error checks so that `else block` can't be followed by anything and clauses besides `elseif` and `else` are errors.

Comment: Good answer! It works for return perfectly. Now I noticed that also continue and break do not behave as expected (which makes sense). I tried to do the same for them as for return, but it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'll try to poke at those cases later today.

Comment: Getting them working is harder than I expected.

Comment: Yes, I also expected it to be easier.